# android app installs but i can't open on android 4.4.2

Tags: android

i have built an app in android studio.

Here is the story so far:

1) the app runs on all my android devices with 5.0 or higher. 2) the app runs in the emulator with Android 5.0 or higher AND android 4.4 as the OS

The issue is that it will not open and run on devices, that is an Android KitKat (Android 4.4.2). I can install the app and see it in the installed apps list, but I cannot OPEN the app, nor will it run on the device

I used the android studio to create the app. Here is the app Gradle.build file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: I would assume your app is trying to run but just crashes right away... Could you look for any errors in your logcat and post them here?

Answer (score 0):

You need set your project's target SDK version lower. In your project, you should set the target SDK version lower than `29`.